# WPF DataGrid: How do you get the content of a single cell?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

How do you get the content of a single cell of a WPF toolkit DataGrid in C#?

By content I mean some plain text that could be in there.

Comment: I know it might sound simple for some, but I am new to WPF and have been trying to do something like in Forms with a DataGridView and have failed to do anything similar. So a detailed solution would be really appreciated!

Comment: Maybe its not that simple after all...

Comment: I think I'll just use a DataGridView from Forms with the help of WindowsFormsIntegration...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following what Phillip said - the `DataGrid` is usually data-bound.  Below is an example where my WPF `DataGrid` is bound to an `ObservableCollection<PersonName>` where a `PersonName` is comprised of a `FirstName` and `LastName` (both strings).

The `DataGrid` supports automatic column creation so the example is quite simple.  You'll see that I can access rows by their index and get the value of a cell in that row by using the property name that corresponds to the column name.

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Create a new collection of 4 names.
            NameList n = new NameList();

            // Bind the grid to the list of names.
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = n;

            // Get the first person by its row index.
            PersonName firstPerson = (PersonName) dataGrid1.Items.GetItemAt(0);

            // Access the columns using property names.
            Debug.WriteLine(firstPerson.FirstName);

        }
    }

    public class NameList : ObservableCollection<PersonName>
    {
        public NameList() : base()
        {
            Add(new PersonName("Willa", "Cather"));
            Add(new PersonName("Isak", "Dinesen"));
            Add(new PersonName("Victor", "Hugo"));
            Add(new PersonName("Jules", "Verne"));
        }
    }

    public class PersonName
    {
        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;

        public PersonName(string first, string last)
        {
            this.firstName = first;
            this.lastName = last;
        }

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return firstName; }
            set { firstName = value; }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return lastName; }
            set { lastName = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew there had to be some way... A bit more complicated then a DataGridView from Forms but WPF is not as mature as Forms.

Comment: No problem.  I think the Xceed (third party) DataGrid uses the DataGridView construct.

Comment: `public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }`

Convert to auto-property :D

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the content of a DataGrid cell is data-bound, and therefore reflect the state of a property (in most cases) of an object which is being displayed in a given row. Hence **it might be easier to access the model rather than the view.**

Having said that (access model not view) my question is: what are you trying to do? Are you looking of **ways to traverse the visual tree** to find the control (or controls) that is rendered on screen? How do you expect to reference the cell, by row and column index?

Comment: For example, with a Forms DataGridView you can do something like this:
string cellContent = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].ToString();

Comment: How can you do something similar with a WPF datagrid?

Comment: And yes I want to be able to get a cell by row and column index.

Comment: I'm looking for something like this too. One good example is that, in DataGridView, you could make a generic copy and paste this way, but this seems to be impossible in WPF DataGrid. Does anybody have insight if this might be possible in the next release of WPF DataGrid?

Answer (score 1):

If you bind using a DataTable you can get the DataRowView from the Row's Item property.

```
DataRowView rowView = e.Row.Item as DataRowView;
```